# jquery random element id for every loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry i'm new in jquery and i need help :-(
  i want to traverse all elements on html page with class parts
then go inside to two children and pass them a random number ( the same for them both)

for every element new random number is passed ( no repeat on page)
children classes are :
anot-head
anot-body
this is a sample code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$.each($('.parts'), function(){
var ran=Math.floor(Math.random()* 1000000);

$( ".anot-head" ).attr( "data-toggle","collapse" ).attr( "href","#s"+ran );
$( ".anot-body" ).attr( "id","s"+ran );

});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(".anot-body")` does a search of the whole document, if you want to find a particular element in another element you need to do a search from that parent element.

In your case you would do a search on the particular `.parts` element that is currently being iterated over in your `$.each()` callback

```
$('.parts').each(function(index,element){
  var parent = $(element);
  var ran=Math.floor(Math.random()* 1000000);
  parent.find('.anot-head').attr( "data-toggle","collapse" ).attr( "href","#s"+ran );
  parent.find('.anot-body').attr( "id","s"+ran );
});
```

Comment: extremely unlikely, but still possible to get duplicates

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `random`.... use index of `each`

```
$('.parts').each(function(index){
  var $part = $(this); 
  $part.find('.anot-head').attr({"data-toggle":"collapse","href":"#s"+index});
  $part.find('.anot-body').attr("id","s"+ index);
});
```